# Problems Installing and working with "pgmpy"

Tags: python, conditional-statements, pgmpy

I am trying to use pgmpy and have used:

```
! pip install pgmpy --user --upgrade pip
```

I then get the error message

```
"TypeError: 'module' object is not callable".
```

I then run the command:

```
from pgmpy.factors import TabularCPD
```

and get a further error message:

```
"No module named 'torch'"
```

Is there a good way to start to work with conditional probability models using Jupyter notebooks?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, it worked for me:

```
conda install -c ankurankan pgmpy
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this installation as pgpy requires pytorch to be installed

```
pip install pgmpy
pip install torch
```